# How to save filtered results in Procmon to a .csv file?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, csv, procmon

I have included the entire script below. It works without this added piece at line 16. If I remove the added code at line 16, the script will complete but does not save the filtered information.

> ```
> /LoadConfig C:\Temp\ProcmonOutlookConfiguration.pmc /SaveApplyFilter /SaveAs C:\Temp\outlook.csv /Quiet
> ```

I ran the script through the debugger and set multiple break points. With the added piece at line 16 the script does not complete and seems to be stuck in a loop at lines 21 and 22.

Question:
How can I fix this so that the script completes correctly and saves the .csv file with the filtered information?

```
clear-host 

$CSVFile = Read-Host "Enter CSV log file and path - (C:\temp\outlook.csv)"
$ProcMonTest = Read-Host "Enter app path - (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE)"
$ProcMon = "C:\tools\Procmon.exe" # this would be the path to wherever procmon.exe is
$ProcMonBack = "C:\Temp\ProcMonTest.pml"
$LaunchBAT = Read-Host "Enter path to the BAT file to launch the app to be tested - (c:\tools\StartOutlook.bat)" # use a bat file to get past PowerShell security
$CredsForApp = $host.ui.PromptForCredential("Run App As?", "Enter creds in domain\username format to run testing app:", "", "") # this gives us the creds to run the app to be tested as 
 
# make sure backing file isn't present in case it wasn't deleted on last run
$FileExists = Test-Path $ProcMonBack
if ($FileExists -eq $true){
Remove-Item $ProcMonBack -force
}
 
& $ProcMon /AcceptEula /Minimized /backingfile $ProcMonBack /LoadConfig C:\Temp\ProcmonOutlookConfiguration.pmc /Quiet
 
do{
Start-Sleep -seconds 90 # procmon.exe /waitforidle doesn't appear to work well when scripted with PowerShell
$ProcMonProcess = Get-Process | where {$_.Path -eq $ProcMon}
}while(
$null -eq $ProcMonProcess.Id
)
(Start-Process cmd -Credential $CredsForApp -Argument "/c $LaunchBAT")

Start-Sleep -seconds 90 # adjust this time based on how long the test run is needed
 
$ProcMonTestProcess = Get-Process | where {$_.Path -eq $ProcMonTest}
Stop-Process $ProcMonTestProcess.Id -Force
 
& $ProcMon /Terminate
 
Start-Sleep -seconds 90 # procmon.exe can take a long time to exit, this ensures it does before proceeding
 
# Read the procmon.exe backing file and export as CSV
& $ProcMon /openlog $ProcMonBack /SaveAs $CSVFile
& $ProcMon /Terminate

Start-Sleep -seconds 60 # procmon.exe can take a long time to exit, this ensures it does before proceeding

# Clean up procmon.exe backing file
$FileExists = Test-Path $ProcMonBack
if ($FileExists -eq $true){
Remove-Item $ProcMonBack -force
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After some further research and rearranging of the script I finally got a the script to save the .csv file with ONLY the Outlook filtered results. This is what I was looking for. Final code below.

```
clear-host 

$CSVFile = Read-Host "Enter CSV log file and path - (C:\temp\outlook.csv)"
$ProcMonTest = Read-Host "Enter app path - (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE)"
$ProcMon = "C:\tools\Procmon.exe" # this would be the path to wherever procmon.exe is
$ProcMonBack = "C:\Temp\ProcMonTest.pml"
$LaunchBAT = Read-Host "Enter path to the BAT file to launch the app to be tested - (c:\tools\StartOutlook.bat)" # use a bat file to get past PowerShell security
$CredsForApp = $host.ui.PromptForCredential("Run App As?", "Enter creds in domain\username format to run testing app:", "", "") # this gives us the creds to run the app to be tested as 
$OutlookConfig = "C:\Temp\ProcmonOutlookConfiguration.pmc" #Path to the saved Outlook configuration file


# make sure backing file isn't present in case it wasn't deleted on last run
$FileExists = Test-Path $ProcMonBack
if ($FileExists -eq $true){
Remove-Item $ProcMonBack -force
}
 
& $ProcMon /Quiet /AcceptEula /Minimized /LoadConfig $OutlookConfig
 
do{
Start-Sleep -seconds 60 # procmon.exe /waitforidle doesn't appear to work well when scripted with PowerShell
$ProcMonProcess = Get-Process | where {$_.Path -eq $ProcMon}
}while(
$null -eq $ProcMonProcess.Id
)
(Start-Process cmd -Credential $CredsForApp -Argument "/c $LaunchBAT")

Start-Sleep -seconds 60 # adjust this time based on how long the test run is needed
 
$ProcMonTestProcess = Get-Process | where {$_.Path -eq $ProcMonTest}
Stop-Process $ProcMonTestProcess.Id -Force
 
& $ProcMon /Terminate
 
Start-Sleep -seconds 60 # procmon.exe can take a long time to exit, this ensures it does before proceeding
 
# Read the procmon.exe backing file and export as CSV with only filtered information
& $ProcMon /openlog $ProcMonBack /SaveAs $CSVFile /SaveApplyFilter 

Start-Sleep -seconds 60 # procmon.exe can take a long time to exit, this ensures it does before proceeding

& $ProcMon /Terminate

# Clean up procmon.exe backing file
$FileExists = Test-Path $ProcMonBack
if ($FileExists -eq $true){
Remove-Item $ProcMonBack -force
}
```